# SSIS - change column meta data from byte stream to unicode string

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssis, ibm-midrange

I have an ADO Net Source to query data from an IBM AS/400.  The column in question is of type CHAR (94).  However, the meta data in SSIS shows it as a byte stream, DTS_BYTES.  If I run the package, I get an error:  data type of "output column "COLUMN_NAME" (38)" does not match the data type "System.String" of the source column "COLUMN_NAME".  It's odd because in SSIS they are both set to DTS_BYTES as the data type.

If I go to the advanced editor for the ADO Net Source, it will let me change the data type of the external column to Unicode string, but not the output column.

I'm not sure why it's coming in as a byte string when the type CHAR should just show up as a string.  (it does in other packages for other columns on the AS/400)  How do I change this metadata so that it shows the external and output columns as Unicode strings instead of byte streams?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd be tempted to experiment with CASTing it until you get a combination that works. (Note, incidentally, that the source code page on the IBM i platform is almost certainly not Unicode.)